# Appium Detect IOS crashes and get crash logs

Tags: ios, appium, appium-ios

I'm working with Appium IOS and I've encountered with a problem
I want to detect when IOS application crashed and I want to retrieve the related crash log. But I couldnt find a proper way to do it with appium's java client.
Is there anyway to do it with appium source code or with any other way

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [idevicecrashreport](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/idevicecrashreport.1.html) from [libimobiledevice](http://www.libimobiledevice.org/)